# With MS Access and SQL, how do I create one table and 1 set of columns from 2 separate SELECT queries on a single table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Background**
I know this question is a little weird, but here's the explanation.

I have `TableA` in my database. I then have two separate queries that contain joins from 2 other master tables:

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM MasterTable_1 INNER JOIN TableA
ON MasterTable_1.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE MasterTabe_1.Field = 'some specific value';
```

and

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM MasterTable_2 INNER JOIN TableA
ON MasterTable_2.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE MasterTabe_2.Field = 'some specific value';
```

I now have values from `TableA` in 2 queries, same columns and everything, but this is really like having 2 tables and I cannot figure out how to get one table and one set of columns from all the data.

**Question**
So, my question is how can I get the `TableA` values from the separate SELECT/JOIN queries into one table with one set of columns where I can call `SELECT DISTINCT` on that final table.

If this requires more explanation let me know. Hopefully I was able to explain it well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use a UNION:

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM MasterTable_1 INNER JOIN TableA
ON MasterTable_1.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE MasterTable_1.Field = 'some specific value';
UNION ALL
SELECT TableA.*
FROM MasterTable_2 INNER JOIN TableA
ON MasterTable_2.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE MasterTable_2.Field = 'some specific value';
```

Comment: I didn't even know UNION existed. Shows how much SQL I know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a UNION? You can also add an additional column to each table with a constant value if you need to still filter inside the single result set.